# Download google finance file from internet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a VBA module in which I want to download the csv file from google finance.

Here is a sample URL

www.google.com/finance/historical?q=LON%3AESSR&ei=dEfGU_ioD4iKwAO3-4HQDg&output=csv

Once I put this URL in browser I get a csv file downloaded. But When I use the "WinHttpReq" object to download the file, I am not getting the csv file. Instead I am getting some HTML.

Is there anyway for me to download this CSV file using the URL in VBA?

Thanks,
Arun.

Comment: If you have code, you should include it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with WINHTTP but I seem to get this working fine - with XMLHTTP. Just enter your file path & name where commented

```
Sub getCSV()

    Dim xhr As Object
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    xhr.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=LON%3AESSR&ei=dEfGU_ioD4iKwAO3-4HQDg&output=csv", False
    xhr.send

    With xhr

        If .Status = 200 And .ReadyState = 4 Then

            myfile = FreeFile

            'HERE
            Open "FILE_PATH_&_NAME.csv" For Output As #myfile
                Print #myfile, .responseText
            Close #myfile

            Set xhr = Nothing

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```